# Passing data from a url for a parameter

Tags: angularjs

Must pass the objects in a url to a parameter . When printing " CONSOLE.LOG (date) " is okay , however when I try to print the contract parameter aprece "Data [object Object] need to assign the values ​​of the object

```
var url = 'http://localhost:55239/api/reports/contracts/';
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function (data) {
            var contract = data;
            console.log("Dados "+ contract);
            console.log(data);
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the required data will be in `data` property of `response`

So, the code should be,

```
var url = 'http://localhost:55239/api/reports/contracts/';
    $http.get(url)
        .then(function (res) {
            var contract = res.data;
            console.log("Dados=");
            console.log(contract);
        }, function(err){
           console.log(err);
        })
```

Also, you are getting `"Data [object Object]` because you are adding a String with object, and hence the browser is trying to show the object as string.

So, `console.log` the data `contract` separately from the String `"Dados="` and you will get to see your data nice and clean.

Any doubt? Ask in comments

Comment: I need to throw the dice into " contract" for I will make a ng -repeat in html and list all the values ​​contained within contract

Comment: If your "contract" is an array, then you can do it like, ng-repeat="c in contract"... Console.log(contract) will show you if it is an array. Use chrome if possible

Comment: Contract is giving as undefined

Comment: when I call the result, he printed the results which not aocntece with contract

Comment: Edited my answer. It should be `then`, not `success`. I have also included a function if your http call fails. Please run it and tell me what's showing in console.

Comment: when i moved for .then work. contract he could assign the os data

Comment: @YehudiMikhael, Happy to help you brother :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties of the `contract` object by using the `.` (dot) operator.

IE:

`console.log(contract.myProperty);`

Answer (score 0):

Just try ;
`var url = 'http://localhost:55239/api/reports/contracts/';
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function (data){
            var contract = data.data;
            console.log("Dados "+ contract);
            console.log(data);
        })`

when you make a call, you receive information related to the response of the request that you made.
For eample when you do data.status it gives you th statuscode that your receive from server.data.daa give you the actual response.

Answer (score 0):

The data appears to be a JSON object.

You can use

```js
console.log("Dados " + JSON.stringify(contract));
```

to print it out with the string.

Comment: I need to throw the dice into " contract" for I will make a ng -repeat in html and list all the values ​​contained within contract

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right way.

The problem is that you are console logging an object `contract` concatenated with a string ´Dados´. So your console shows the `contract as [object]` because its is converting to a string. Try to `console.log(contract)` and you will see the object serialized in the console log.

Pt-BR: está funcionando corretamente, mas como tu ta concatenando uma string com o objeto contratos, o console loga [object] no lugar do contrato e não o objeto serializado com faz normalmente.

See my snippets using both SUCCESS and THEN:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myAppController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  
  $scope.appTitle = "Http demo";
  $scope.contractUsingSuccess = [];
  $scope.contractUsingThen = [];
  $scope.loadingPostsSuccess = true;
  $scope.loadingPostsThen = true;
  
  var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  $http.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.contractUsingThen = response.data;
    $scope.loadingPostsThen = false;
  });
  
  $http.get(url)
  .success(function (contract) {
    $scope.contractUsingSuccess = contract;
    $scope.loadingPostsSuccess = false;
  });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myAppController">
    <h1 ng-bind="appTitle"></h1>
    
    <h2>Using Success</h2>
    <div ng-show="loadingPostsSuccess">Loading posts from API with SUCCESS...</div>
    <ul ng-show="!loadingPosts">
      <li ng-repeat="item in contractUsingSuccess" ng-bind="item.title"></li>
    </ul>
    
    <h2>Using Then</h2>
    <div ng-show="loadingPostsThen">Loading posts from API whit THEN...</div>
    <ul ng-show="!loadingPosts">
      <li ng-repeat="item in contractUsingThen" ng-bind="item.title"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the contract is not getting the Json object data passed through the URL

Comment: @YehudiMikhael, Use `then`, instead of `success`. See my edited answer

Comment: Actually it is getting. The problem is the way that you are using the console.log. Try to change `console.log("Dados "+ contract);` to `console.log(contract);` and see if the console logs the rigth object.

Comment: @SumanBarick, using then does not answer the question. Why complicate the user with this comment?

Comment: It is working , but I wanted him to just bring the "id " and " name " .

Comment: @vinagreti, somehow he is not getting the data and I corrected him. And not to mention I also saw you edit your own answer from `success` to `then` just after my comment. If it was not helpful Why did you do that?

Comment: In this case you can access the object properties as `console.log(contract.id);` and `console.log(contract.name);`

Comment: he is bringing it all: 
Dados =  
[Object]: 
  Object
         id: 4 
        name: "Test"
  Array[0]

Comment: When I put " contract.name " he says that is undefined

Comment: @SumanBarick Just because this is the right way to use promisses after Angular 1.3. My point is that I did not mention that to te user. He want to get the data and not to think about using then or success. We are here to solve problems not to grow up them.

Comment: No, we are here to HELP people learn. StackOverflow is for developers. From Developers, to Developers. We are not customer service executives. And, I still do not get How I confused him by showing the right way? :O

Comment: Now you have a snippet that uses both, THEN and SUCCESS. You can see that both work. But ok, the problem is solved. Thanks @SumanBarick

Comment: @vinagreti, welcome friend, also thanks to you for conveying the thoughts / idea to him in his language. As I do not know that language, hence the credits goes to you in that section :)